# I don't know why write system call seems not been delay

Tags: c, linux, unix

```
int main(){    
    int fd = open("aaaaaa.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
    
    write(fd, "a", 1);

    system("more aaaaaa.txt");

    unlink("aaaaaa.txt");
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

I want to ask why this data is written to the file immediately(by 'more' I can see this), instead of being directly written to the kernel page cache(not really write in file) and after a period of time,then page cache be really written to file by flusher thread .

Comment: What are you basing your conclusions on?

Comment: `write` writes to "the file". `more` reads from "the file". Whatever "the file" is, a page cache, magentic variations on disk or symbols hacked in stone, is from the perspective of a c program, just a minor implementation detail.

Comment: Note this behavior is required by the POSIX standard: any operation that provably takes place after a `write()` call must see the new data.  Here, the execution of `more` certainly takes place after the `write()`, because `system("more")` comes after `write()` in your program.  So if a system is going to have a page cache, it must be coherent, and all programs must read from it, not directly from the disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is written to the kernel page cache. And `more` reads from the kernel page cache. The kernel page cache is shared by all processes, because it is in the kernel.